# How to get the Selected Text from Active Control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, controls, clipboard, selectedtext

Is there a way to get the selected text or highlighted text only from the Active Control? Active Control doesn't have `.SelectedText` option, so I used `.Text`

Example in the image.

I only highlighted **"Rus"** from the `EnhacedTextBox`.

`ActiveControl.Text` contains **"Russia".**

How do I get the SelectedText **"Rus"** to be set in `Clipboard.SetDataObject()` for copying?

[image]

Thanks a lot for your opinions and suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get selected text of a textbox?

Comment: yes, since the active control type is the textbox. How do I get the selected text from that textbox? Thank you.

Comment: The `ActiveControl` property is type `Control`, so you can only access members of the `Control` class. If the actual control itself is a type that has a `SelectedText` property then you need to cast as that type to be able to access members of that type. If it might be a type other than that then you need a conditional cast, i.e. use `TryCast`. Make sure you read about that and how to use it first.

Comment: Of course, if the control is a `TextBox` then you don't need to get the selected text and copy it yourself, The `TextBox` class has a `Copy` method.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney `TryCast` was the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get selected text of a textbox ? If so,you can use `TextBox.SelectedText` property.

I am not sure if you are looking for this but if no, then i assume you are generating multiple textboxes from code behind/during design time ? If so, then try the following code to get the active textbox :

```
Private Sub GetTheText()
If Me.ActiveControl.[GetType]() = GetType(TextBox) Then
    Dim textBox As TextBox = CType(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox)
    Dim mytext = textbox.SelectedText
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
m_strGetText = Me.m_udtNavigationController.TemplateKeyAss.PrimaryTask.ActiveControl.Text.ToString()
        Dim trial As EnhancedTextBox = TryCast(Me.m_udtNavigationController.TemplateKeyAss.PrimaryTask.ActiveControl, EnhancedTextBox)
        Dim trial2 As String = trial.SelectedText().ToString()
```

Solution from @jmcilhinney.

`trial2` now contains the `Rus` selected text. Thanks.

Comment: That's not how you use `TryCast`. I specifically said that you should read up on it. The whole point of `TryCast` is that it will return `Nothing` if the specified object is not the specified type rather than throw an exception. If the `ActiveControl` will definitely be the specified type then you should be using `DirectCast` and if it might not be then you should be testing the result of `TryCast` for `Nothing`.

Comment: Also, given that `SelectedText` is type `String`, there's not much point calling `ToString` on it.